# SQL - Wildcard search with AND

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the scenario.

We have a field named "Description", the requirement is:

1. User can give max 5 words to search the result. 
   eg : ab and cd and ef and gh and ij
2. It will give that description which has all the above 5 words in it.

Can anyone please tell me how can this be accomplished.

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Aarti

Comment: [Full text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search) perhaps.

Comment: Do you have a full text index on that table?

Answer (score 1):

```
select description from tablename where 
description like '%word1%' and
description like '%word2%' and
description like '%word3%' and
description like '%word4%' and
description like '%word5%'
```

It would be useful to know what happens to "words" if they are less than 5. Are they null? Are they ''? Example with null:

```
....(description like '%word2%' or word2 is null) and...
```